# Enhancing windows explorer to view mkv-tags in details-panel

Tags: windows-10, mkv

As the title says, I'm looking for a software that adds the ability to view mkv-meta-data in the details panel of the windows explorer (not the data columns you can add to folder view).

Some tags seems to be supported by windows-10 out of the box as the mkv-tags for "TITLE", "GENRE" and "LAW_RATING" are already displayed in the details panel of the windows explorer, along with those for every file like "file-size", "last-modified", "created" and nearly every video file like "width", "height", "duration", "total-bitrate" and "fps".

Others, like "PRODUCER", "DIRECTOR", "DATE_RELEASED", "ACTOR" and "SUMMARY" are not displayed. Even if I've select the corresponding data-columns they stay empty, so this tags seems to be not recognized by windows.

I've tried Icaros and it works... more or less. It shows mkv-embeded cover art as thumbnails in windows explorer. But even if "property-support" is enabled in Icaros, the details panel of windows explorer only shows the "file-size", "last-modified" and "created". If I uninstall Icaros (or disable property support), everything is like before with "duration", "TITLE" and so on displayed in details panel.

So long story short, are there any tools that adds mkv-tag (reading) support to windows explorer (details panel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I ended up with the following solution:

There is a specific registry value for each fileType/fileExtension that specifies what elements should be displayed in the details pane.

In my case its about .mkv files:

1. Open the registry editor (Ctrl + R) -> "regedit"
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv`
3. Get the default value (in my case this is `VLC.mkv`)
4. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{value-from-step-3}` (in my case `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.mkv`)
5. Create a string value named `PreviewDetails`. If this value already exists, backup its contents if you want to be able to restore the current behavior. To do so, just edit this value again and paste the original-data. If this value has not existed before, then delete the created string-value `PreviewDetails` to restore the default behavior.
6. Edit the string value of `PreviewDetails` to something like this `prop:System.Title;System.Video.Director;System.Media.Writer`. The `prop:` prefix is written once, then a semicolon separated list of the properties you want to show should follow. Not all properties are supported by all file types. And not all properties are located in the category where you would look for them ;)
7. Backup the created registry string since updating your favorite player might overwrite your modified settings.

List of all properties:
[MSDN: System.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521735%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[MSDN: List of all categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thumbnail/cover support seems to be not possible the registry-way, you still need something like Icaros - which might be combinable with this registry-way to get both: tags and cover. **not tested**

*EDIT*
Seems like the windows explorer is able to show embeded-covers in details pane too - without Icaros. Disabled cover and property support in Icaros and then uninstalled it. Windows explorer is still showing the embeded *landscape* cover in details pane. Lets see if this survives a reboot :)

*EDIT2*
Still works after reboot :)

*EDIT3*
For some unknown reason no cover is displayed for some files, but MediaInfo and VLC do recognize the cover...

And last the list of properties that I'm using as well as the mkv-tags that will be used as source. The number is the target number of the mkv-tag-group in the xml-tag-file:

```
System.Title:               MKV.50.TITLE (movie-title or episode-title)
System.Video.Director:      MKV.50.DIRECTOR
System.Media.Writer:        MKV.50.WRITTEN_BY
System.Media.Producer:      MKV.50.PRODUCER
System.Media.DateReleased:  MKV.50.DATE_RELEASED
System.Music.Genre:         MKV.50.GENRE
System.Media.Publisher:     MKV.50.PUBLISHER
System.ParentalRating:      MKV.50.LAW_RATING
?:                          NKV.50.ACTOR
?:                          MKV.50.SUMMARY

?:                          MKV.70.TITLE (name of the series or collection)
System.Media.SeriesName:    ? (see System.Title)
System.Media.SeasonNumber:  MKV.60.PART_NUMBER
System.Media.EpisodeNumber: MKV.50.PART_NUMBER

System.Video.FrameWidth
System.Video.FrameHeight
System.Video.FrameRate
System.Audio.EncodingBitrate
System.Video.EncodingBitrate
System.Video.TotalBitrate
System.Media.Duration
System.DateCreated
System.DateModified
System.Size
System.OfflineAvailability
```

Comment: Did you find a way to display actor and summary fields? I can't get them to work. All other fields are being displayed property as you explained.

Comment: @PuffLord No, sadly not :( Might be not possible for now... All fields that I was able to match to windows-system-property are short strings of one or just a few words. Actor' would be a long list and summary could also be a long string - may be thats the reason for not adding them... :/